# Can I go to the implementation in the c project with lsp?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I'm separating the functions from `main.c` to `func1.c` `func2.c`, then I'm using `util.h` to store the prototype (all name of all functions).

### PROBLEM

when I try to go to implementation, lsp leading me into `util.c`, but i want to leading to `func1.c`

##### main.c

```c
#include "util.h"

int main(){
  int x = fun||c1(); // here || is cursure location !
  int y = funct2();
  //...
}
```

##### util.c

```c
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int func1();
int func2();
//...
```

##### func1.c

```c
int  func1(){
  //...
}
```

##### Makefile

```
all: main

main: func1.o func2.o ... main.o
    gcc func1.o func2.o ... main.o -o main

func1.o: func1.c util.h
    gcc func1.c

func2.o: func2.c util.h
    gcc func2.c
#...
```

#### my env:

i use:

- `neovim` as `ide`
- `lspconfig` plugin handle `lsp`
- `ccls/clangd` is tow `lsp` for `c/cpp`
- `:lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()` go to implementation but lead me to `util.h`
- `:lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()` go to definition but lead me to `util.h` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the implementation depends on the way the project is built. You can tell `clangd` about this using [`compile_commands.json`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html).

You can generate this file using [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear): `bear -- make`.

Bear is probably available in your package manager.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, clangd is not able to jump to `func1()` via "Go To Definition" or "Find References" capabilities because there is not a direct link to `func1.c`.

As an alternative, you can use tags. You will need to install one of the flavors available (:h ctags). I recommend the package `universal-ctags`. Run `ctags -R .` in your root directory and simply type `<c-]>` to go to the first match or `g <c-]` to show a list if there are several matches.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here for `clang` users who also want neovim LSP go-to functions to work on C projects built with `CMake`.

1. You can have CMake generate a `compile_commands.json` as follows:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 ..
   ```
2. Move this new file from your build directory (if applicable) to the root of you project.
3. If new source files are added to your project you may need to rerun 1 & 2.

I found this got `vim.lsp.buf.definition()` and `vim.lsp.buf.references()` working in my C project when lots of other tries failed.